# Hyperledger: The required parameter 'sequence' is empty. Rerun the command with --sequence flag

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying out the NFT Auction repo at https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/nft-auction

I get the error

`Error: The required parameter 'sequence' is empty. Rerun the command with --sequence flag`

```
Finished vendoring Go dependencies
Skipping Chaincode packaging and installing...
Using organization org1
Installed chaincodes on peer:
Query installed successful on peer0.org1 on channel
Using organization org1
Error: The required parameter 'sequence' is empty. Rerun the command with --sequence flag
Usage:
  peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg [flags]

Flags:
      --channel-config-policy string   The endorsement policy associated to this chaincode specified as a channel config policy reference
  -C, --channelID string               The channel on which this command should be executed
      --collections-config string      The fully qualified path to the collection JSON file including the file name
      --connectionProfile string       The fully qualified path to the connection profile that provides the necessary connection information for the network. Note: currently only supported for providing peer connection information
  -E, --endorsement-plugin string      The name of the endorsement plugin to be used for this chaincode
  -h, --help                           help for approveformyorg
      --init-required                  Whether the chaincode requires invoking 'init'
  -n, --name string                    Name of the chaincode
      --package-id string              The identifier of the chaincode install package
      --peerAddresses stringArray      The addresses of the peers to connect to
      --sequence int                   The sequence number of the chaincode definition for the channel
      --signature-policy string        The endorsement policy associated to this chaincode specified as a signature policy
      --tlsRootCertFiles stringArray   If TLS is enabled, the paths to the TLS root cert files of the peers to connect to. The order and number of certs specified should match the --peerAddresses flag
  -V, --validation-plugin string       The name of the validation plugin to be used for this chaincode
  -v, --version string                 Version of the chaincode
      --waitForEvent                   Whether to wait for the event from each peer's deliver filtered service signifying that the transaction has been committed successfully (default true)
      --waitForEventTimeout duration   Time to wait for the event from each peer's deliver filtered service signifying that the 'invoke' transaction has been committed successfully (default 30s)

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --connTimeout duration                Timeout for client to connect (default 3s)
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --tlsHandshakeTimeShift duration      The amount of time to shift backwards for certificate expiration checks during TLS handshakes with the orderer endpoint

Chaincode definition approved on peer0.org1 on channel 'defaultchannel' failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

Tried looking at the Issues tab of the repo

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a `--sequence` number to the command. The first time the chaincode is deployed it should be set to '1', and then increment from there.

For example:

`peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --channelID mychannel --name basic --version 1.0 --package-id $CC_PACKAGE_ID --sequence 1 --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem"`

See the full example at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy_chaincode.html#approve-a-chaincode-definition.